# Facebook Login WinForms Username

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, oauth, desktop-application

I made a windows application and in it I use a web browser control on a separate form that enables the user to login using his Facebook account, I use the oauth interface to get the access token then user's information, all works fine but the only thing is that that it's a desktop application, so multiple users can use the same PC, which in turn multiple users can use the same application, upon first time login the login dialog asks for username and password, but for the next logins I cant enter a different username unless I clear the history of all browsers, so is there a way like using some certain parameter with the request, or some setting from the Facebook application that forces the user to enter the username on every login attempt ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, check below.

Invalidating (aka logout) your token; make HTTP GET call to that endpoint;

```
https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=auth.expireSession&format=json&access_token=<access_token>
```

Do this on each program start

Comment: thanks for the answer, although i found out that my case is different but your answer is correct for my description, when it came to my mind that if i logged out the user from my app, the user will be logged out from the browser as well, which is not convenient for the customer, i don't think there is a way to log out depending on the session, isn't there?

Comment: If you want to logout user from facebook site(not from your oauth session) you shoold use getlogouturl from facebook sdk.